how to change persmission of bluetooth app?
I find bluetooth and nfc app every day sometimes running even if bluetooth in menu show off
and need to press force stop button to stop the app
android bluetooth has so much permission such as location , nearby device, SMS, Files and Media
"device requires this permission to operate" how to change this permission to deny?
